# MySQL: select max combination of 2 columns and distinct 3rd

Tags: mysql

I have the following table of devices:

```
| id   | name                                                  | width   | height   | storage_aspect_ratio | created_at          | updated_at          | status   | type   |
|------|-------------------------------------------------------|---------|----------|----------------------|---------------------|---------------------|----------|--------|
| 18   | Apple Cinema Display 30                               | 2560    | 1600     | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 19   | Apple iMac 21.5-inch (Late 2009 - Late 2012)          | 1921    | 1080     | 1921:1080            | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 20   | Apple iMac 21.5-inch (Retina 4K Display)              | 4096    | 2304     | 16:9                 | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 21   | Apple iMac 27-inch (Late 2009 - Late 2012)            | 2560    | 1440     | 16:9                 | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 22   | Apple iMac 27-inch (Retina 5K Display)                | 5120    | 2880     | 16:9                 | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 23   | Apple iPad 1 & 2                                      | 768     | 1024     | 3:4                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 2      |
| 24   | Apple iPad 3 & 4                                      | 1536    | 2048     | 3:4                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 2      |
| 25   | Apple iPad Air                                        | 2048    | 1536     | 4:3                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 2      |
| 26   | Apple iPad Air 2                                      | 2048    | 1536     | 4:3                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 2      |
| 27   | Apple iPad Mini                                       | 768     | 1024     | 3:4                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 2      |
| 28   | Apple iPad Mini 2                                     | 2048    | 1536     | 4:3                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 2      |
| 29   | Apple iPad Mini 4                                     | 2048    | 1536     | 4:3                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 2      |
| 30   | Apple iPad Pro                                        | 2732    | 2048     | 683:512              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 2      |
| 31   | Apple iPad Pro 9.7                                    | 2048    | 1536     | 4:3                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 2      |
| 32   | Apple iPhone 11                                       | 828     | 1792     | 207:448              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 33   | Apple iPhone 11 Pro                                   | 1125    | 2436     | 375:812              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 34   | Apple iPhone 11 Pro Max                               | 1242    | 2688     | 207:448              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 35   | Apple iPhone 3GS                                      | 320     | 480      | 2:3                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 36   | Apple iPhone 4 (4, 4S)                                | 640     | 960      | 2:3                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 37   | Apple iPhone 5 (5c, 5s)                               | 640     | 1136     | 40:71                | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 38   | Apple iPhone 6                                        | 750     | 1334     | 375:667              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 39   | Apple iPhone 6 Plus                                   | 1080    | 1920     | 9:16                 | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 40   | Apple iPhone 6s                                       | 750     | 1334     | 375:667              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 41   | Apple iPhone 7                                        | 750     | 1334     | 375:667              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 42   | Apple iPhone 7 Plus                                   | 1080    | 1920     | 9:16                 | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 43   | Apple iPhone 8                                        | 750     | 1334     | 375:667              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 44   | Apple iPhone 8 Plus                                   | 1080    | 1920     | 9:16                 | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 45   | Apple iPhone SE                                       | 640     | 1136     | 40:71                | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 46   | Apple iPhone X                                        | 1125    | 2436     | 375:812              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 47   | Apple iPhone XR                                       | 828     | 1792     | 207:448              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 48   | Apple iPhone XS                                       | 1125    | 2436     | 375:812              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 49   | Apple iPhone XS Max                                   | 1242    | 2688     | 207:448              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 3      |
| 50   | Apple MacBook 12-inch                                 | 2304    | 1440     | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 51   | Apple MacBook Air 11-inch                             | 1366    | 768      | 683:384              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 52   | Apple MacBook Air 11-inch (Late 2010 - Mid 2012)      | 1366    | 768      | 683:384              | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 53   | Apple MacBook Air 13-inch                             | 1440    | 900      | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 54   | Apple MacBook Air 13-inch (Late 2010 - Mid 2012)      | 1440    | 900      | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 55   | Apple MacBook Pro 13-inch                             | 2560    | 1600     | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 56   | Apple MacBook Pro 13-inch (Mid 2009 - Mid 2012)       | 1280    | 800      | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 57   | Apple MacBook Pro 13-inch (Retina display)            | 2560    | 1600     | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 58   | Apple MacBook Pro 15-inch                             | 2880    | 1800     | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 59   | Apple MacBook Pro 15-inch (Early 2006 - Mid 2012)     | 1440    | 900      | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 60   | Apple MacBook Pro 15-inch (Hi-Res screen)             | 1680    | 1050     | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 61   | Apple MacBook Pro 15-inch (Retina display)            | 2880    | 1800     | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 62   | Apple MacBook Pro 17-inch (Mid/Late 2007 - Late 2011) | 1920    | 1200     | 8:5                  | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
| 63   | Apple Thunderbolt Display 27                          | 2560    | 1440     | 16:9                 | 2020-12-15 17:16:02 | 2020-12-24 16:24:28 | 1        | 1      |
```

I need to get the distinct `storage_aspect_ratio` based on the **max** combination of `width` and `height`. The closest I've been able to get is the following query, but I think it's still pretty far off.

```
SELECT width, height, storage_aspect_ratio
FROM wallpaper_device
    NATURAL JOIN
       (SELECT GREATEST(width, height)
        FROM wallpaper_device
        GROUP BY width, height) AS max
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY width, height, storage_aspect_ratio
ORDER BY width DESC;
```

<strike>It would also be nice to return the entire row data (name, width, height, storage_aspect_ratio, status, type). That's why I didn't use distinct, because the name will always return all results. Is this possible? Or should I filter it in code?</strike>

In thinking about it more, the name is not important, so distinct could be used?

I'd like to get this result:

```
| width | height | storage_aspect_ratio | status | type |
|-------|--------|----------------------|--------|------|
| 2880  | 1800   | 8:5                  | 1      | 1    |
| 1921  | 1080   | 1921:1080            | 1      | 1    |
| 5120  | 2880   | 16:9                 | 1      | 1    |
| 1536  | 2048   | 3:4                  | 1      | 2    |
| 2048  | 1536   | 4:3                  | 1      | 2    |
| 2732  | 2048   | 683:512              | 1      | 2    |
| 1242  | 2688   | 207:448              | 1      | 3    |
| 1125  | 2436   | 375:812              | 1      | 3    |
| 640   | 960    | 2:3                  | 1      | 3    |
| 640   | 1136   | 40:71                | 1      | 3    |
| 750   | 1334   | 375:667              | 1      | 3    |
| 1080  | 1920   | 9:16                 | 1      | 3    |
| 1366  | 768    | 683:384              | 1      | 1    |
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the result you want with the given sample data as table.

Comment: @stickybit I thought I had included the result set. I've updated my question and realized the name isn't important.

Comment: can "max combination of width and height" be "maximum product of width and height"? ie `max(width * height)`?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
select storage_aspect_ratio, max(width * height) as pixels
from wallpaper_device
where status = 1
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/122788/2).

Comment: I tried something like this, but my SQL editor gives me an error:

`Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wallpaper_device.width' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: I still get that error, the only way I can get the query to execute is this:

`select storage_aspect_ratio, max(width * height) as pixels
from wallpaper_device
where status = 1
group by width, height, storage_aspect_ratio
order by (width * height) desc;`

But then I get multiple `storage_aspect_ratio` results that are the same.

Comment: @Nfourteen The query works: See live demo. Also, `group by width, height, storage_aspect_ratio` won't work (properly). Try just copy pasting my query into your environment.

Comment: To get by the error message, I used:

`select storage_aspect_ratio, max(width * height) as pixels
from wallpaper_device
where status = 1
group by storage_aspect_ratio
order by pixels desc;`

Thanks @Bohemian for the help!

Comment: @Nfourteen no problem. BTW even simpler SQL will work - see edit.

Comment: Is there any way to include the specific widths and heights in the result? Meaning, I'd like to get the distinct width/height combo associated with the storage_aspect_ratio where pixels is the greatest.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bohemians query BUT add MAX in the order by.  See below.

```
SELECT storage_aspect_ratio, MAX(width * height) AS pixels
FROM wallpaper_device
WHERE STATUS = 1
GROUP BY storage_aspect_ratio
ORDER BY MAX(width * height) DESC
```

Then you won’t get the irritating error message.  Adding all the columns to the group by will defeat the max you’re trying to get.  That’s why you were getting so many results doing that.